# Why does moving this face cause vertices to merge?

Tags: edit-mode, transforms, topology

I have a surface like this:

[image: Surface before moving]

I press G, then X to move the face out. Before clicking to apply the movement, the face looks like this:

[image: Surface while moving]

Finally, when I click to apply the move, the edges on the face that I'm moving merge (I do not want this):

[image: Applied move]

**What is causing this and how can I avoid it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have automerge enabled, with a high threshold.  In edit mode, look on sidebar/tool/automerge.  Disable it if enabled.

Comment: Yep. That was it! Thanks for your help :) I'll mark it as the correct answer soon, as the timer won't let me right now.